# Are there any new ways to change the color of the hamburger menu icon

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, hamburger-menu

The Application hast 3 different Colorthemes. White, black and grey. Is there a new and easy method to change the Hamburger icon dynamically with the backgroundcolor? So if the theme is grey or white, the icon should be black and if the theme is black, then the icon should be white. I am working with Xamarin.Forms PRISM.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on below link :

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69113/how-can-i-change-the-hamburger-icon-for-another-one-in-xamarin-forms-for-android

Or you may try this:-

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomIcon.Views.MainPage), typeof(IconNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace CustomIcon.Droid
{
    public class IconNavigation : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = GetToolbar();
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;

                    var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable; 
                    if (drawerArrow == null)
                        continue;

                    imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.newIcon));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```